# remove controller name from the url to make url clean in sub directory codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have created a blogs inside sub directory because my main directory is running an html website so the blog system needs to be created with codengiter i developed and added inside a folder named blogs now the problem is that i want ot make parameters dynamic right now the url is

domainname.com/blogs/posts/test

I want it to be like give below
domainname.com/blogs/test

can any one help me out how do I do that

I have created route as given below

```
        `$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'blogs/posts/$1';`
```

my controller

```
       `class Blogs extends CI_Controller {
        public function posts($slug = null) {
            echo "hello world";
        }
        }``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code like this need to accept variable to 'Controller blog' and pass it to the function post

`$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blogs/posts/$1';`